# Web start (jnlp) problem with Oracle 7 Java

Tags: jdk, jre

I have just met a annoying problem with my java. I tried to install jre and jdk on my Ubuntu 12.04 but something must have go wrong. I can run *java -version* to see java version and *javac -version* to see javac version, even test java in chrome. But I can't run *jnlp* file. When I try to open it, nothing happens. What should I do now? Thank you.

Comment: I have solved this problem. I reinstalled oracle-java7-installer and it now works well.

Answer (score 1):

*OP has solved and wrote : :*

> I have solved this problem. I reinstalled oracle-java7-installer and
>   it now works well.

*I have put it as answer because it can be useful to other people in future.*